# Data Ingestion: Receive and decode Message files(.txt) in Real Time

Tags: python, message-queue, data-integration, data-ingestion

We have a requirement in our project to read and decode Message Text files in real time. The files are received by a Third Party using MQ Setup. The requirement is to extract the files from MQ Server, Store it in our system, decode using a spec and store the data in a Database table.

This is the proposed flow:

***Message Files(.txt) --> MQ Server --> ?? --> Decode --> Store in DB***

Questions:

1. 3rd Party already has an MQ setup and they are ready to push it to us. May i know how can I subscribe to their MQ system to receive the files? Is it possible to use SFTP to receive the files or I should have an MQ setup at my side?
2. We already have a source code in Python to decode the files but not sure on how to do this end to end processing real time as and when the files are pushed to our side.

Answer (score 1):

1. Should you use SFTP? No, configure your side to subscribe to the 3rd party's MQ channel. That is necessary to minimize end-to-end latency.
2. That's a bit vague. Show us the code you have written so far that listens on the channel and dispatches to your decoder. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks J_H.. I have the code only to read the files from SFTP and decode but not from MQ.. Since i am not clear how to use MQ, I raised this question.. Is it possible to receive message files using MQ at our side and decode the files real time and store them in DB? If so, can you give me some details around that?

Comment: You will want to go through an MQ tutorial, run it yourself, tweak it, and see how its behavior changes. Then you will be in a position to subscribe to the 3rd party's MQ channel, or at least ask them sensible questions. Your client will get a piece of text from the channel for each message event, encoded in some way such as JSON. Then it's up to the client to parse and act on the message.